# Show a div if check box is checked and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the value of a check box and then if it is checked it should show my div id as resizeable. If its not checked it should disappear. This is what I tried:

```
var showheader = document.getElementById("ckbx_header").checked;

if ( showheader == checked ) {
    $("#resizeable").toggle("slide", {}, 1000) );
  };
```

Comment: Why would you use `document.getElementById` when you have `$()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're really trying to do what you say you are, do this:

```
if($('#ckbx_header').prop('checked'))
    $("#resizeable").toggle("slide", 1000);
```

Otherwise, look at [Felix Kling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177453/how-do-i-check-a-check-box-for-being-true-or-false-and-toggle-hide-an-element-i/6177509#6177509)

Comment: Note that this requires jQuery 1.6 (or did 1.5 add `.prop()`?) - anyway, <1.5 do not support it for sure.

Comment: Note that ".prop()" is a 1.6 thing; code using older versions of the library would use ".attr()". *edit* ha ha great minds etc

Comment: @rikki ewan: Then you asked for the wrong thing. Or you're using jQuery <1.5

Answer (score 2):

You can bind an event handler to the `change` event:

```
$('#ckbx_header').change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         $("#resizeable").slideDown(1000);
     }
     else {
         $("#resizeable").slideUp(1000);
     }
});
```

In any case you need two actions: Show the div when the checkbox is selected and hide it if not. Currently you are toggling the visibility whenever the checkbox is selected, which is not what you want.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to not repeat the erroneous `toggle('slide' ...`

Comment: @Yoshi: This seems to be an extension by jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/

Comment: King Oh, my bad. But of regardless of that, I think your solution is the most reusable, because whithout the `onChange` binding this whole thing wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: perfect perfect congratuations  five starts *****

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the extra check in the if, the checked value returns a boolean.

This would work:

```
var showheader = document.getElementById('test').checked;

if(showheader)
 $("#resizeable").toggle("slide",{},1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you should use it fully imo and do:

```
if ($("#ckbx_header:checked").length) {
    $("#resizeable").toggle("slide", {}, 1000) );
};
```

The :checked selector will only match if the element is a checked checkbox.